# Does it hold that $\{a\}'' = \{f(a) : f$ bounded, Borel measurable$\}$?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an Hilbertspace. Let $a\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ be a self-adjoint operator. Does it hold that $\{a\}^{\prime\prime}=\{f(a):f\in L^{\infty}(\sigma(a))~\text{Borel measureable}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a detailed proof in Section IX.8 in Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", taking a couple pages.